# Reaper failed to run repair on Cassandra nodes

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

After Reaper failed to run repair on 18 nodes of Cassandra cluster, I ran a full repair of each node to fix the failed repair issue, after the full repair, Reaper executed successfully, but after a few days again the Reaper failed to run, I can see the following error in system.log

```
ERROR [RMI TCP Connection(33673)-10.196.83.241] 2021-09-01 09:01:18,005 RepairRunnable.java:276 - Repair session 81540931-0b20-11ec-a7fa-8d6977dd3c87 for range [(-606604147644314041,-98440495518284645], (-3131564913406859309,-3010160047914391044]] failed with error Terminate session is called
java.io.IOException: Terminate session is called
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.ActiveRepairService.terminateSessions(ActiveRepairService.java:191) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]

INFO  [Native-Transport-Requests-2] 2021-09-01 09:02:52,020 Message.java:619 - Unexpected exception during request; channel = [id: 0x1e99a957, L:/10.196.18.230:9042 ! R:/10.254.252.33:62100]
io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress() failed: Connection timed out
```

in `nodetool tpstats` I can see some pending tasks

```
Pool Name                         Active   Pending
ReadStage                              0         0
Repair#18                              3        90
ValidationExecutor                     3         3
```

Also in `nodetool compactionstats` there are 4 pending tasks:

```
-bash-4.2$ nodetool compactionstats
pending tasks: 4
- Main.visit: 1
- Main.post: 1
- Main.stream: 2
```

My question is why even after a full repair, reaper is still failing? and what is the root cause of pending repair?

PS: version of Reaper is 2.2.3, not sure if it is a bug in Reaper!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely don't have enough segments in your Reaper repair definition, or the default timeout (30 mins) is too low for your repair.
Segments (and the associated repair session) get terminated when they reach the timeout, in order to avoid stuck repairs. When tuned inappropriately, this can give the behavior you're observing.
Nodetool doesn't set a timeout on repairs, which explains why it passes there. The good news is that nothing will prevent repair from passing with Reaper once tuned correctly.

We're currently working on [adaptive repairs](https://github.com/thelastpickle/cassandra-reaper/pull/1107) to have Reaper deal with this situation automatically, but in the meantime you'll need to deal with this manually.
Check the list of segments in the UI and apply the following rule:

- If you have less than 20% of segments failing, double the timeout by adjusting the `hangingRepairTimeoutMins` value in the config yaml.
- If you have more than 20% of segments failing, double the number of segments.

Once repair passes at least twice, check the maximum duration of segments and further tune the number of segments to have them last at most 15 mins.

Assuming you're not running Cassandra 4.0 yet, now that you ran repair through nodetool, you have sstables which are marked as repaired like incremental repair would. This will create a problem as Reaper's repairs don't mark sstables as repaired and you now have two different sstables pools (repaired and unrepaired), which cannot be compacted together.
You'll need to use the `sstablerepairedset` tool to mark all sstables as unrepaired to put all sstables back in the same pool. Please read [the documentation](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/tools/sstable/sstablerepairedset.html) to learn how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

There could be a number of things taking place such as Reaper can't connect to the nodes via JMX (for whatever reason). It isn't possible to diagnose the problem with the limited information you've provided.

You'll need to check the Reaper logs for clues on the root cause.

As a side note, this isn't related to repairs and is a client/driver/app connecting to the node on the CQL port:

```
INFO  [Native-Transport-Requests-2] 2021-09-01 09:02:52,020 Message.java:619 - Unexpected exception during request; channel = [id: 0x1e99a957, L:/10.196.18.230:9042 ! R:/10.254.252.33:62100]
io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress() failed: Connection timed out
```

Cheers!